# Hierarchical linear regression (HLR) - can I perform each model/step using an Robust Linear Model (RLM)?

Tags: r, linear-regression, hierarchical, robust

**BACKGROUND**:
I'm conducting a hierarchical linear regression using R (specifically R studio, Version 4.1.3). I want to use robust linear models (using the `rlm` function, MM-estimator) for each of my step, instead of a traditional OLS model (`lm` function). This is because I have some influential outliers.

1. For example, here is an example of my "STEP 1"/"Model 1" code:

**Note*: used the `f.robftest` function from the `sfsmisc` package to get p-values from beta-coefficients:*

```
model1_controlsRLM = rlm(ER40_CR ~ Age_in_Yrs + Gender2, data = datasetfinal, method = c("MM"))
f.robftest(model2_EFcontrolsRML, var = "Age_in_Yrs")
f.robftest(model2_EFcontrolsRML, var = "Gender21")
```

2. Example of "STEP 2"/MODEL 2 code:

```
model2_EFcontrolsRML = rlm(ER40_CR ~ Age_in_Yrs + Gender2 + CardSort_AgeAdj, data = datasetfinal, method = c("MM"))
f.robftest(model2_EFcontrolsRML, var = "Age_in_Yrs")
f.robftest(model2_EFcontrolsRML, var = "Gender21")
f.robftest(model2_EFcontrolsRML, var = "CardSort_AgeAdj)
```

3. And then comparing models using an ANOVA

```
anova(model1_controlsRLM, model2_EFcontrolsRML)'
```

[Missing p-values here, and also not sure how to compare changes in R^2 or an equivalence metric that would communicate similar information]

**MY QUESTIONS**

- 1. Is it allowed to use an RLM (instead of standard OLS) for each step/model in a hierarchical linear regression?
- 2. If so, how can I calculate changes in adjusted R^2 or an equivalent metric appropriate for RLMs? [I'm open to using a different estimator instead of MM (e.g., M-estimator) if this makes a difference].
- 3. How do I get the p-values of my ANOVA comparing the two RLM models (comparing step 1 vs. step 2)

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: As an update, I believe I found a solution for getting the R^2 and adjusted R^2 values: it seems like `robustbase` package has the `lmrob` command and output gives a lot of information on how the RLM is weighted & R^2 & adjusted R^2 estimates. This youtube video was helpful:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qte9ASvgElI

If anyone has an opinion of whether you can use an RLM as a part of an HLR, I would love to hear input on this part.

Comment: Hi! While you are using R, some of your questions are more related to the statistical methods implemented, so they might be better suited for https://stats.stackexchange.com/